# send fax with Elastix and Hylafax

Tags: asterisk, fax, elastix

I need help getting around "Unknown problem" while I am trying to send faxes using Hylafax and Elastix.

I have an elastix 4.0 inside a VM, calling outside and inside the box is working great, using zoiper from a pc in the network.

I need to send faxes but I got stuck with "Unknown problem" error:

I have installed 2 virual faxes with IAX extensions following the guidelines here: http://elastix.wikia.com/wiki/FAX_Setup_@_Elastix on the virtual fax list both have the status Running and idle on ttyIAX1 and ttyIAX2

extensions 7001 and 7002 
I also have a SIP extension 8004 registered on local computer

Then I dial from 8004 -> 7001 I get the fax tone ( OK )

but When I try to send a fax from 7001 -> 8004 , Zoiper rings but the moment I answer the fax machine hangs up, status on the interface: Unknown problem

when I try to send a fax from 7001 -> 7002 I got the same result

here are the Hylafax logs:

```
Apr 12 18:25:58.59: [25524]: SESSION BEGIN 000000106 408004
Apr 12 18:25:58.59: [25524]: HylaFAX (tm) Version 4.3.11
Apr 12 18:25:58.59: [25524]: SEND FAX: JOB 17 DEST 8004 COMMID 000000106 DEVICE '/dev/ttyIAX1' FROM 'Asterisk VoIP PBX <asterisk@asterisk.harrison.ro>' USER asterisk
Apr 12 18:25:58.59: [25524]: STATE CHANGE: RUNNING -> SENDING
Apr 12 18:25:58.59: [25524]: <-- [12:AT+FCLASS=1\r]
Apr 12 18:25:58.59: [25524]: --> [2:OK]
Apr 12 18:25:58.59: [25524]: MODEM set XON/XOFF/FLUSH: input ignored, output disabled
Apr 12 18:25:58.59: [25524]: DIAL 8004
Apr 12 18:25:58.59: [25524]: <-- [9:ATDT8004\r]
Apr 12 18:26:20.52: [25524]: --> [6:DTMF=9]
Apr 12 18:26:20.52: [25524]: SEND FAILED: JOB 17 DEST 8004 ERR Unknown problem
Apr 12 18:26:20.52: [25524]: <-- [5:ATH0\r]
Apr 12 18:26:20.52: [25524]: --> [2:OK]
Apr 12 18:26:20.52: [25524]: MODEM set DTR OFF
Apr 12 18:26:20.52: [25524]: MODEM set baud rate: 0 baud (flow control unchanged)
Apr 12 18:26:20.52: [25524]: STATE CHANGE: SENDING -> MODEMWAIT (timeout 5)
Apr 12 18:26:20.52: [25524]: SESSION END
```